# Rendering highest integer value from three models instances in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have three models which are related all to one model.

```
class MyModelParent(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_lenght=36, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name or ""

class MyFirstModel(models.Model):
      mymodelparent = models.ForeignKey(MyModelParent, related_name="first_models", blank=True, Null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
      ranking = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=36, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name or ""

class MySecondModel(models.Model):
      mymodelparent = models.ForeignKey(MyModelParent, related_name="second_models", blank=True, Null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
      ranking = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=36, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name or ""

class MyThirdModel(models.Model):
      mymodelparent = models.ForeignKey(MyModelParent, related_name="third_models", blank=True, Null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
      ranking = models.IntegerField(max_lenght=36, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.ranking or ""
```

I am rendering MyParentModel in DetailView (CBV) and passing related models as a context to render individual models 'ranking' field on the same template.

Now I need to render same 'ranking' on MyParentModel ListView, but I only want to display 'ranking' which has highest value.
Question is, how I can compare my related models 'ranking integer value' and display highest on MyParentModel ListView page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare different fields using [Greatest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) and compare the values of the fields themselves using `Max()` - an [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/) will return to you the single greatest value:

```py
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest

MyModelParent.objects.aggregate(
    max=Greatest(
        Max('first_models__ranking'),
        Max('second_models__ranking'),
        Max('third_models__ranking'),
    )
)

# output: {'max': 230}
```

**Edit** - Explanation

There are three parts to this query:

1. **Max** - this finds the maximum value of the provided field, we are using double underscore notation to access the `ranking` field of the related model because `ranking` is not a field of `MyModelParent`.
2. **Greatest** - because `Max` only works on fields, we cannot use it to find the max of the max (if that makes sense). Instead, we need to use `Greatest` which is a DB function (whereas Max lives within `django.db.models`) and returns the greatest value from said list. We therefore provide it with each of our `Max` values from the three different models.
3. **Aggregate** - we just want the single highest figure and aggregate will squash the queryset into a dictionary - we can add other values to this if we want. Annotate can also be used if we want each queryset object to have access to this value.

Comment: Thanks 0sVoid, it does work but displays same highest figure for each record in the listview... i.e. whichever record has highest value it is populated for each record. Any solution here?

Comment: Use `annotate` instead of aggregate if you want each record in the queryset to have the max value